# Logging without IDE

Tags: debugging, avr-toolchain

Is there a way to log events on Arduino when developing using C / AVR toolchain, and not the Arduino IDE? Working on Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you want your host system to record stuff received from an Arduino?  Or do you want an Arduino to record data?  Either way, the answer is yes, it can be done.

Comment: First one, I would like to see on my host what Arduino is doing.

Comment: The IDE uses a plain serial console to communicate with the Arduino.  You can use any serial console application you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Ubuntu, I usually simply do

```
stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 raw 9600
cat /dev/ttyACM0 > the.log.file
```

Replace 9600 with your baud rate of choice.

Comment: Ha, neato. No character encoding mangling woes?

Comment: @user400344: The command is encoding agnostic: it moves the data from the serial port to the file as a _byte stream_, not a _character stream_. It could well be binary data for that matter.

Comment: Thanks, it will replace my terrible hack completely. Do you use something similarly simplistic to send data to your MCUs?

Comment: @user400344: No, I use text-based protocols, like in this [command line interpreter](https://gist.github.com/edgar-bonet/607b387260388be77e96), and type the stuff directly at the keyboard, usually through [screen](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/screen). You could `cat the.data.to.send > /dev/ttyACM0` but, since the Arduino resets when you open the port, your sketch will miss the beginning of the file. You can avoid this auto-reset feature by putting a cap between RESET and 5V.

Comment: pretty neat. what value should I use for the cap?

Comment: I just use tip, I never liked screen

Comment: @user400344: 10 µF is recommended by the [ArduinoISP tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP), 1 µF always worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at microbox which is similar to your interpreter. I like the clarity of your str-fu better, though. +1

Answer (score 1):

Any of these are straightforward: python (serial library) or processing (same type of user interface, will happily build portable java programs for linux/win/mac). I use an awful perl script for logging stuff, can't recommend it. If you don't prefer the two first options, have a look at IPC::Open2 or IPC::Open3 - I use a bidirectional connection so I can send stuff, but I rely on 'tip' to do the serial connection stuff. If I wanted to log more than a few things, I would probably use python, which is much easier to read (later), and it will require a small fraction of the memory a fullblown java applet.